# How to make a non fading animation in CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a blinking animation for a piece of text that goes from black to white instantly with no fading. Right now it fades to to white then instantly snaps to white

my code:

```
.flash {

    animation-name:blinkAni;
    animation-duration:1s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@keyframes blinkAni {
        0% {color:black}
        100% {color:white}
}
```

Comment: It is because you have the duration set as 1s. try using a delay so it waits then changes instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [animation-timing-function: steps(1)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function) property and set your white state at 50%:

```css
.flash {
    background: #CCC;
    animation-name:blinkAni;
    animation-duration:1s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    animation-timing-function: steps(1);
}

@keyframes blinkAni {
   0% {color:black}
   50% {color:white}
}
```

```html
<p class="flash">Hello</p>
```